# Getting value of A in ARGB background color in android programmatically

Tags: android, alpha, argb

Suppose i have background color set as #**AF**000000(**AA**RRGGBB) in android.
I want value of alpha channel(**AA**) in decimal (0-255) which is going to be 175.

How to accomplish that programatically?

Comment: you may convert hex2decimal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a pure Java solution that doesn't use the Android-specific `getAlpha()` method.

Do you have this value stored in a `String` or an `int`? If you have it in a `String`, first get rid of the `#` character then convert it to an `int`:

```
String hexString = "#05000000";
int color = Integer.parseInt(hexString.replaceAll("#", ""), 16);
```

Then we need to make some bit manipulation. This hex color representation means (in ARGB mode) you have the values #AARRGGBB. That is 2 bytes for each channel, including the alpha one. To get just the alpha channel (the `AA` part of the hex value), we need to *"push it 6 bytes to the right"* (Java is a [Big Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) languange) so we can end up with something like `#000000AA`. Since each byte is comprised of 8 bits, we have to *"push"* the alpha values `6 * 8 = 24` bits *"to the right"*:

```
int alpha = color >> 24;
```

This process is called [Bit Shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). All the rightmost RGB values are discarded and we then have the alpha value stored in an `int` with a decimal value between 0 and 255.

**EDIT:** If you already have the alpha value as returned from getAlpha(), you can always multiply it by 255 and floor it:

```
int alpha = Math.floor(myView.getAlpha() * 255);
```

Comment: I agree with this idea. But just convert decimal value to the closest corresponding integer where 0 is 0 and 1 is 255. Then convert into hex. This prevent you to work with String too much.

Comment: Does the info provided answer your question? If so, please mark this as accepted. If not, tell us why in the comments so we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You may convert your HEX to Decimal Simply use,

```
int i= Integer.parseInt(HEX_STR,16);
```

or if you need to pass long hex value means use like,

```
public static long hexToLong(String hex) {
return Long.parseLong(hex, 16);
}
```

Comment: you have said "here HEX_STR is your getAlpha() in HEX."But  getAlpha () returns value between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

To get each individual int value:

```
            int argb = Color.parseColor("#00112233");
            int alpha = 0xFF & (argb >> 24);
            int red = 0xFF & (argb >> 16);
            int green = 0xFF & (argb >> 8);
            int blue = 0xFF & (argb >> 0);
```